# OPEN_APP_FEATURE Action in Android Studio

Tags: android, google-assistant-sdk, app-actions

we are trying to integrate an action in google assistant. I want to open my activity with an extra intent. Users will say "Ok Google, beni bul" (means find me) and with this our app will open and send their location into our webservice. I followed Built-In-Intent documentary and tested in App Action Test Tool. When i published my application into playstore it was denied because Turkish language was not supported. Also instead of test tool, when i test directly in assistant, it returns me web results.

```
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter
            android:autoVerify="true"
            tools:targetApi="m">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data
                android:host="acilizmir.page.link"
                android:scheme="https" />


        </intent-filter>

    </activity>

<actions>
  <action intentName="actions.intent.OPEN_APP_FEATURE" >
    <fulfillment urlTemplate="https://acilizmir.page.link/open{?featureName}" >
        <parameter-mapping
            intentParameter="feature"
            urlParameter="featureName" />
    </fulfillment>

    <parameter name="feature" >
        <entity-set-reference entitySetId="FeatureEntitySet"  />
    </parameter>
</action>

<action intentName="actions.intent.GET_THING">
    <fulfillment urlTemplate="https://acilizmir.page.link/open?q={q}">
        <parameter-mapping
            intentParameter="thing.name"
            urlParameter="q"/>
    </fulfillment>
</action>

<entity-set entitySetId="FeatureEntitySet" >
    <entity
        name="bul"
        identifier="bul" />
    <entity
        name="find"
        identifier="find" />
</entity-set>
```

Answer (score 0):

That's correct. Turkish is currently not supported in App Actions. Stay tuned for updates.